# Keep up server performance with systemd

Tags: memory, performance, systemd, resources

I would like to execute a long-running, memory-intensive task without influencing the performance of my server. My server has 4GB RAM and I created a 30GB swap file.

There is very memory-hungry programm (which does complex queries on a huge database) which - after a time - stresses the server so much that I'm even unable to login via ssh.

My plan was to limit the resources of this programm via systemd.
First, prevent swapping for user and system programms:

```
# systemctl edit user.slice
[Slice]
MemorySwapMax=0
```

And

```
# systemctl edit system.slice
[Slice]
MemorySwapMax=0
```

Then, create a slice for the memory-intensive programm:

```
[Slice]
CPUAccounting=true
CPUShares=512
MemoryLimit=1G
MemoryMax=1.1G
MemorySwapMax=infinity
```

This should prevent the programm from using more than 1GB RAM but allows it to swap as much as it wants - right?

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Either the programm gets killed or the server is unreachable after a while (when playing around with the values).

Is this, what I like to do, possible? If so, how would I do that?

**Edit: my solution**

```
echo 100 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/<myswappingslice>.slice/memory.swappiness
echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/memory.swappiness
echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/memory.swappiness
```

That's all.
I assign the memory-consuming service to .slice so that it will swap aggressively and doesn't use up all the RAM.
With the preventing user.slice and system.slice from swapping, the overall performance of the server is not negatively influenced.

Comment: Do you have a a physical server or a rented virtual server? If you are renting a virtual server, the host may have additional constraints on your resource usage.

Comment: Most reliable way I have found on the internet to keep remote server sshd responsive with i/o swap thrashing on a system. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `MemorySwapMax=` directive was introduced in systemd 232. If you are using an older version, this directive may not be available to you.

There is no directive named `MemoryMax=`, but there is `MemoryLimit=`.

See `man systemd.directives` for a list of all directives in your installed version of systemd, including references to the `man` pages they are documented in.

Answer (score 1):

MemoryMax= exists, but it's fairly new and older versions of systemd may not be using it.

Check documentation here.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html